# Javascript to Dynamically Include Keywords in Landing Page

Tags: javascript

First, let me apologize for being a complete novice here. I took a Javascript course 13 years ago and seem to have forgotten most of it. Anyway, I found some code online to dynamically include keywords on our page that are sent via URL from our Google ads. I'm using Jimdo to create a free website and they allow you to add code to the Body, but not sure if you can add to the Head. Anyway, when I add the code below to the Body, nothing happens. What, where and how should this code be placed in order to work?

Example: http://www.yourdomain.com?utm_term={keyword}

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split(“&”);
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split(“=”);
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
}

searchTerms = getQueryVariable(‘utm_term’);

if (searchTerms.length != 0) {
    searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(/+/g, ” “);
    searchTerms = unescape(searchTerms);
    document.write(“<h1>This headline is about ” + searchTerms + “</h1>”);
}
else {
    document.write(“<h1>This headline is generic.</h1>”);
}
```

Comment: One question - are you using the `“ ”` (double left/right quote) and `‘ ’` (single left/right quote) in your JavaScript? Or, the `"` (double quote) and `'` (single quote)? There's a difference!

Comment: Thanks Jack. What you see is exactly what was cut/pasted from the site I found the code.

Comment: My bet is that's the issue! The `double left/right` quotes (or `fancy` quotes as i like to call them) are causing an exception. Sometimes they pop up if you copy/paste and other times it depends on the text editor. Let me throw a fiddle together really quick!

Comment: http://www.brooksbell.com/blog/developer-download-how-do-i-use-javascript-to-dynamically-include-keywords-in-landing-page-headlines/

Comment: Thanks again...above is the link to the site/blog where I found this. So from what you're saying....all the double left/right quotes should be changed to single quotes? I know you're doing the fiddle thing and I appreciate that.

Comment: Hey, no problem @h20field. Yeah, I did a copy/paste from that blog and they're using "fancy" quotes (left/right double/single quotes). If you replace those, your script will be good. One other thing I noticed was a regex error, but that was a quick fix as well!

Comment: also should point out that it needs to be wrapped in `<script>...</script>` tags

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dnd4kepr/

There were two issues:

1. The single/double *left/right* quotes (`“&”`) (or fancy quotes) were throwing exceptions. You'll want to replace those bad boys with just your plain jane single/double quotes (`"&"`).
2. Once the fancy quotes were replaced, there was an exception thrown due to the regex. You'll want to escape the `+` character like this: `searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(/\+/g, ' ');`

Once those two things were done, the script started working!

Comment: Awesome Jack! I spent a better part of the day trying to figure it out. whish I would have posted on here sooner. I'll work on this now and will post back the results.

Comment: Hi Jack. I tried copying the code from fiddle. I noticed you had some code that referred to the html and CSS blocks. I haven't seen or used fiddle, but I assume you needed to refer to that code to make things work. Anyway, I removed what code I thought wouldn't be needed for my page, but i must be doing something wrong. Here is a cut/paste from what is on the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
}


searchTerms = getQueryVariable('utm_term');

if (searchTerms.length != 0) {
    searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    searchTerms = unescape(searchTerms);
    write('<h1>This headline is about' + searchTerms + '</h1>');
}
else {
    write('<h1>This headline is generic.</h1>');
}
}, false)
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look!

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var terms = getParameterByName('utm_term')
    var h1 = document.createElement('H1');

    /*
      or if you want to hook to existing el
      var h1 = document.getElementByTagName('h1');
      if there is only one `h1` on the page
      and remove document.body.appendChild(h1) at the end
    */

    if (terms) {
        var searchTerms = terms.replace(/\+|\,/g, " "); // not sure how you want to format
        h1.innerText = "This headline is about " + searchTerms;
    } else {
        h1.innerText = "This headline is generic."
    }
    document.body.appendChild(h1);

})();
```

Do you already have `<h1>` in your html? If so, then you should access it with either jquery or vanilla js and then do `innerText` on that el. Let me know and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Denis. I see that this is a completely different method. I'll take a look. As for already  having the <h1> in the html,..I'm not sure. The site (Jimdo) only provides the tools to manipulate text.

Comment: Hi Denis. I copied/pasted the code onto the page and wrapped in <script>...</script>. The code seems to function, but not text (write) is being generated on the page...regardless if the URL has the ‘utm_term’ at the end. Do you think this has to do with the <H1> question you had? I'd like to get this functioning, so i'm okay with eliminating the H1

Comment: Hi Denis...you had helped me with the above script a few months back. I took a break from this because I wasn't having any success. However, I tried again today and it now seems to work in IE, but not Firefox. Not sure why. I hope you will get this post because I feel I'm getting very close to getting this to work. Here is a link to the HTML page I'm working on. It only has the script and nothing else. http://www.thepiezoexchange.com/threeJS_Codes.html ....I'm hoping you might know why it doesn't work in Firefox. It could be an issue with the settings on my computer, but not sure